# RoR using Chained Selects jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a jQuery chained select.
This is a sample of the HTML that is needed (not the code I'm using - but, will give you an idea how the jquery requires the HTML to look):

```
<select id="mark">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="series">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="series-3" class="bmw">3 series</option>
  <option value="series-5" class="bmw">5 series</option>
  <option value="series-6" class="bmw">6 series</option>
  <option value="a3" class="audi">A3</option>
  <option value="a4" class="audi">A4</option>
  <option value="a5" class="audi">A5</option>
```

My RoR app has clients, projects, and tasks
I need the class in the task options to contain the project.id

Right now I'm using Simple-Form and the code looks like this:

```
<%= collection_select(:project, :projname, Project.all, :id, :client_project, {}, {:class=>'project_select'}) %>
<%= f.association :task, :label_method => :taskname, :label => 'Task' %>
```

The collection lists the projects (I've concatenated the client to the project). So the first part of the HTML is fine.

But, how can I get the association code to use the project.id as the class for each task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon your question, and I know it's old, but I've solved this using `simple-form` in the following manner:

```
= form.input :task do
    = form.select :task_id, Task.all.map { |t| [t.taskname, t.id, { :class => t.project_id }] }, :include_blank => true
```

Essentially you use the simple_form wrapper `input` but define some custom HTML to use within the wrapper (in this case it's using the Rails `select` form helper). The Rails helper allows you to pass the class as per @pduersteler's answer.

I'm using HAML in my views in case that wasn't clear :)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use `select` instead of `collection_select` and passing your collection to `select` with using the `options_for_select` helper. Using `options_for_select` allows to pass html as a third attribute. See here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select

Controller: `@projects = Project.all.map{ |p| [p.projname, p.id, {:class => p.id}] }`
View: `select(:project, :projname, options_for_select(@projects), {:class=>'project_select'})`

**untested and may need modification**